# Why Met malfunction when running code MPI?

Tags: python

I installed Microsoft MPI and mpi4py and installed enviroment and operator is Microsoft. Why I run code. I met malfunction is
mpiexec -np 4 python MPI_Exam_canon.py

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0-1] terminated

[2] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Init_thread(argc_p=0x0000000000000000, argv_p=0x0000000000000000, required=3, provided=0x000000FB997EE1B8)
No such host is known.  (errno 11001)

[3] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[2] on NG?CC??NG
mpi has detected a fatal error and aborted python

---- error analysis -----

Help me please!!! Whyyyy???
I try to fix it but impossive to run it